# How to generate a content based sha1 for hash table?

Tags: c++, git, algorithm, hash

In my project, I need to generate an sha1 for a given object via serialization interface, like this:

```
class sha1_sink : public isink{...};

sha1_sink sink;
serialize(sink, obj);
return sink.get_digest();
```

serialize is a template function and overloaded for different type.

It works well in most of cases, except hash table.

By the design, if object A has the same content as B, they should have same sha1. The order is meaningless to a hash table, so if hash table A and B have same elements, but the orders are different, they should be considered same.

One solution is to sort it first at the begging of function serialize, but obviously, it's slow and requires extra memory.

May I can rehash it via setting the load factor with a predefined value, such as 0.5, before serializing, and I think the order of elements would be stable, even it requires to tweak the hash table.

But I think none of above is good enough and I want to seek a better solution. I would be very appreciate if someone can show me how to get onto the right path.

For the hash table, it's a general purpose container, just like std::unordered_map/set.

Comment: how many elements in your hashtable in worst case?

Comment: I think 10k is a reasonable assumption in my project.

Comment: I'm not sure why you cross-posted this to [tag:git], but I'll note that Git's `tree` objects, which have a similar problem in some ways, are always built from a *sorted index*, i.e., Git takes the "keep the hash table sorted" approach. This is fine for Git because once a tree *exists* as an in-database-object, it can never be changed; the sorting work happens elsewhere, and its cost is amortized over other uses of the index.

Comment: Just xor all the contained hashcodes together, that's order-independent.

Comment: it's too aggressive i think, but it inspired me, may i can search a better algorithm.

Comment: @torek my project intends to make a git-like repository to support versioning, and it would store serialized objects  instead of files. for the `tree`,  i use std::map at runtime. i think sort a tree is reasonable, because the buddy operation is IO, and usually the element number of a `tree` is not very large, so the extra cost should be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, by hashtable, you're meaning `std::unordered_map<K, V>` or your own implementation.

If the entries in your hashtable are relatively few and insertion-deletion operations are limited, you can use `std::map<K, V>` (and I hope your serilization template has overloaded methods for `std::map`) or equivalent data-structure which will guaranty sorted order under the hood (balanced binary search tree). So, the serialized objects will yield equal I hope. Operations on `std::map` take logarithmic time so for 10k entries, its reasonable `log2(10k) = 10` operations per insertion/deletion.

As you said, you have around 10k entries, I think it won't be a good idea to use fixed load factor as it may affect hashtable performance.

Comment: i appended some info in my question. 
tweak the load factor is not a good ideal, agreed.

the hash table would be used for general purpose by user programmer. std::map has already been supported. I want to provide hash table just because it's better than std::map in some time sensitive query.